# Is it possible to deploy a non-portlet WAR file in JBOSS Portal?

Tags: java, angular, gwt, portlet, jboss-portal

Recently I had to migrate a **GWT portlets** UIs to Angular2 UIs. The problem is that the application is huge containing plenty of modules (portlet-war files) which are embedded inside a **JBoss Portal** (v 2.7) as **Tabs**.

So to avoid the "tunnel effect" of the migration, our strategy consists of keeping the JBoss Portal and migrating the portlet-war files one by one (so that portlet-war files and non-portlet war files can coexist) until we totally get rid of the portal.

The problem is that after spending hours on searching if we can deploy a simple war (not a portlet) inside a JBoss Portal as a **Tab**, we didn't get any result...

So I'm asking if it is possible to deploy a non-portlet WAR file in Jboss Portal?

Comment: Do you want to deploy the Angular2 application as a tab (portlet), or on its own context (`/myangularapp`)?

Comment: Then I don't get it... You want it to be a portlet, but you say in the question "simple war, not a portlet". Which one is it? O_o

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding I want a "simple war not a portlet" but that can be deployed on JBoss Portail as a **Tab**  (I modify my last comment)

Answer (score 0):

A Portal is composed of UI elements and portlets. I assume that each tab is a portlet in your portal, so, for an AngularJS application to be available there as a tab, you have to deploy it as a portlet.

A portlet can be as simple as a WAR file with a minimalist `portlet.xml`. Just package your AngularJS application into the WAR, add a simple `portlet.xml` to `WEB-INF`, and deploy it. Once it's deployed, you are able to add your AngularJS as a tab to your portal. You might want to take a look at the GateIn examples, like these:

https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal/tree/master/examples/portlets/jquery

https://github.com/gatein/gatein-portal/tree/master/examples/portlets/simplesthelloworld

Comment: By the way, I just realized that you are talking about JBoss Portal 2.7. I have only a vague memory about what JBoss Portal 2.7 looks like, so, I have no idea if my answer applies to that :-)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! Adding the `portlet.xml` is not a problem but as you can see with your `jquery sample`, we need to add `gatein-resources.xml`, define scripts add supports...etc. so I'm afraid that we will be spend too much time trying to adapt the Angular2 **non-portlet WAR** with a a Portal (like Gatein)...
What do you think?